# Android - Animate popup dialog with bounce effect

Tags: android, animation, view

Hey all, I'm trying to animate a custom dialog box so that when it pops up it has a kind of bounce effect (it starts small, gets large, then bounces a little smaller then back to normal size).

I have no idea how to start this task.  What should I be looking at to animate this view, how is it done?

Comment: Care to share an XML that would produce that effect?  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an animation and animation layout in XML and use `android:layoutAnimation` in your XML layout.  Search the SDK for `Animation Resources`.

Comment: I didn't know you could do it with XML.  Found this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html.  Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome. this was the page i was refering to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html